# Installing python packages in a custom dir

Tags: django

I installed "django-openid-auth" and it copied the egg to the django installation directory. I would like my installations to happen in a "plugins" directory within the django app. How would I do this? I checked options under python setup.py --help but couldn't find anything. Can I just copy everything from the site-packages folder into the plugins folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["Custom Installation"](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#custom-installation)